# Exception when accessing system registers from EL2 on QEMU GICv3

Tags: arm, interrupt, qemu, armv8

I have some baremetal AARCH64 software running in QEMU. I am trying to access GICv3 system registers ICH_* from EL2, but I keep getting an exception when I read/write to it.

```
ESR 0x2000000: ec 0x0, il 0x2000000, iss 0x0


x0  0xffffffff000bd2c0 x1                 0x3 x2  0xffff00004808cd50 x3  0xffff00004808cd20
x4          0x77616974 x5          0x65766e74 x6          0x74696d72 x7                   0
x8                   0 x9          0xffffffff x10 0xffff0000401fc870 x11 0x4a49524200000000
x12                  0 x13 0xffffffff00131000 x14 0xffff000042290000 x15 0xffff0000401fc730
x16 0xffffffff00117100 x17 0xffff0000401feb80 x18 0xffffffff00117100 x19 0xffff00004808ccb0
x20                  0 x21 0xffff0083dd174db8 x22 0xffff00004808cd38 x23 0xffff00004806eba8
x24 0xffff00004806f028 x25 0xffff00004808ccc8 x26 0xffff0083dd174e18 x27            0x80000
x28                0x1 x29 0xffff0083dd174d50 lr  0xffffffff000bc5a0 usp                  0
elr  0xffffffff000bd2c0
spsr         0x20000305
```

I have enabled SRE by setting up ICC_SRE_EL2 register

Am I missing something?

-kim

Comment: What is the value of the 'GIC CPU' field in the ID_PFR1_EL1 register ? It should probably be 0x1 (GIC CPU interface is enabled) for any access to the GIC using the CPU interface to work.

Comment: Please note that ID_PFR1_EL1seems to be a read-only register. That is, if the 'GIC CPU' field in the ID_PFR1_EL1 register of your emulated target is set to 0, you may have to fall-back on the memory-mapped GIC interface.

Comment: What is your QEMU command line? (In particular, if you're using the 'virt' board, have you enabled the GICv3? Are you using KVM, or emulation?) QEMU's GICv3 emulation is system-registers-only, so this does work at least well enough that Linux can use the GIC from EL2.

Comment: @Frant Thank you! With that said I came across this https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-arm/2017-11/msg00092.html 

Looks like I need to upgrade to 2.11 in order to have the correct ID_PFR1_EL1. Thoughts?

Comment: @PeterMaydell my command line looks something like this -machine gic_version=3 -machine virtualization=true; 

I am using QEMU emulation

Comment: I made a test using 2.11 at EL3:  ID_PFR1_EL1.GIC is 1, which is good, but I got an exception attempting to access an ICH_ register. Did not test at EL2 yet. You may have to build 2.11 by hand, since versions provided with major Linux distributions are usually not the latest one.

@Peter Maydell: the command line I used with QEMU 2.11 was:

qemu-system-aarch64 -m 256M -semihosting -machine virt,gic-version=3,secure=on -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:1235,server,nowait -cpu cortex-a53 -nographic -kernel  cpugic.elf

Comment: @Frant yeah I am seeing similar problem, I still get the same exception when accessing ICH_ system register from EL2

Comment: Frant: your command line doesn't have '-machine virtualization=on' so it won't define the ICH_* registers. Strictly that's a QEMU bug as they should be RES0 from EL3 if EL2 is unimplemented, but it's not a very interesting corner case. kimi: which particular ICH_ register are you trying to read? Give the disassembly of the insn which is failing...

Comment: @Frant I am trying to read ICH_HCR_EL2 

#define ICH_HCR_EL2 "S3_4_C12_C11_0"
__asm__ volatile("mrs %0, " ICH_HCR_EL2 : "=r"(temp));

Comment: @Peter Maydell
Thank you, I can now read ICH_AP1R0_EL2 at EL3 by using the virtualization=on option. I can read  ICH_HCR_EL2 at EL3 as well.

Here is my output from objdump:

    42000db0: d53cc900  mrs x0, s3_4_c12_c9_0
    42000db4: f90013a0  str x0, [x29, #32]
    42000db8: d53ccb00  mrs x0, s3_4_c12_c11_0
    42000dbc: f9000fa0  str x0, [x29, #24]

Kimi, I would second Peter Maydell: you should use aarch64-elf-objdump for verifying the instruction is properly encoded.
You could try to read ICH_HCR_EL2 at EL3, using -machine secure=on,virtualization=on, since it worked for me.

Comment: Kimi, a slightly modified version of your code worked fine for me at EL3:  
`uint32_t temp = 0;`
`#define ICH_HCR_EL2 "S3_4_C12_C11_0" `
`__asm volatile("mrs %0, " ICH_HCR_EL2 : "=r"(temp));`

Forgot to mention I used  a slightly modified version of Linux `arch/arm64/include/asm/sysreg.h` file for my own tests.

Comment: I used the objdump to get the below

 ffffffff000bdcb8:   d53ccb00    mrs x0, s3_4_c12_c11_0
 ffffffff000bdcbc:   d5033f9f    dsb sy
 ffffffff000bdcc0:   d65f03c0    ret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what should be a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for your use case:
a) Create a `ich_hcr_l2.S` file in `/tmp`:

```
#define             ICH_HCR_EL2 S3_4_C12_C11_0

                    .arch   armv8-a
                    .globl _start
                    .text
_start:
#ifdef __RETURN_CURRENT_EL__
                    // test only - returning CurrentEL
                    mrs  x0, CurrentEL
                    ubfx x0, x0,2,2
#else
                    mrs x0, ICH_HCR_EL2
#endif
                    // exiting/returning w0 using Angel/Semihosting interface
                    adr x1, status
                    str w0, [x1]
                    mov w0, #0x18
                    adr x1, code
                    hlt #0xf000     

                    .data
                    .balign 8
code:               .dword 0x00020026
status:             .dword 0x00000000
                    .end
```

b) Create an executable shell script named `ich_hcr_l2.sh` in `/tmp`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Absolute path to this script. /home/user/bin/foo.sh
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $BASH_SOURCE)

# Absolute path this script is in. /home/user/bin
SCRIPTPATH=$(dirname $SCRIPT)

set -e 
QEMU_VERSION=2.11.0
QEMU_SYSTEM_ARM=${SCRIPTPATH}/qemu/bin/qemu-system-aarch64

build_qemu()
{
  if [ ! -f ${SCRIPTPATH}/qemu/bin/qemu-system-aarch64 ]
  then
    if [ ! -f ${SCRIPTPATH}/qemu-${QEMU_VERSION}.tar.xz ]
    then
      wget https://download.qemu.org/qemu-${QEMU_VERSION}.tar.xz
    fi
    rm -rf ${SCRIPTPATH}/qemu-${QEMU_VERSION}
    tar Jxf ${SCRIPTPATH}/qemu-${QEMU_VERSION}.tar.xz -C ${SCRIPTPATH}
    pushd qemu-${QEMU_VERSION}
    ./configure --target-list="aarch64-softmmu" --prefix=${SCRIPTPATH}/qemu
    make all install
    popd
  fi
}

build_example()
{
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc ${CFLAGS} -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -Wl,-Ttext=0x0000000042000000 -o ${SCRIPTPATH}/ich_hcr_l2.elf ${SCRIPTPATH}/ich_hcr_l2.S
  aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -D ${SCRIPTPATH}/ich_hcr_l2.elf > ${SCRIPTPATH}/ich_hcr_l2.lst
}

run_example()
{
  # exit code will be the context at w0 register.
  ${QEMU_SYSTEM_ARM} -m 256M -semihosting -machine virt,gic-version=3,virtualization=on,secure=${SECURE} -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:1235,server,nowait -cpu cortex-a53 -nographic -kernel ${SCRIPTPATH}/ich_hcr_l2.elf
  printf "Program returned with w0=%d\n" $?
}

# main
build_example
build_qemu
set +e 
# testing program - should return CurrentEL=2
CFLAGS="-D__RETURN_CURRENT_EL__"
SECURE=off
build_example
run_example

# testing program - should return CurrentEL=3
CFLAGS="-D__RETURN_CURRENT_EL__"
SECURE=on
build_example
run_example

# actual test case: retrieving ICH_HCR_L2 at EL2:
CFLAGS=""
SECURE=off
build_example
run_example
```

c) make /tmp your current working directory, and execute ich_hcr_l2.sh, then be patient: the script will download, then build qemu-system-aarch64 2.11.0 from its source code.

After a while, you should see the following two three being displayed:

```
Program returned with w0=2
Program returned with w0=3
Program returned with w0=0
```

and /tmp/ich_hcr_l2.lst should contain:

```
/home/eperie/aarch64/ich_hcr_l2.elf:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000042000000 <_start>:
    42000000:   d53ccb00        mrs     x0, s3_4_c12_c11_0
    42000004:   100800e1        adr     x1, 42010020 <status>
    42000008:   b9000020        str     w0, [x1]
    4200000c:   52800300        mov     w0, #0x18                       // #24
    42000010:   10080041        adr     x1, 42010018 <code>
    42000014:   d45e0000        hlt     #0xf000

Disassembly of section .note.gnu.build-id:

0000000000400120 <.note.gnu.build-id>:
  400120:       00000004        .inst   0x00000004 ; undefined
  400124:       00000014        .inst   0x00000014 ; undefined
  400128:       00000003        .inst   0x00000003 ; undefined
  40012c:       00554e47        .inst   0x00554e47 ; undefined
  400130:       e7c953ee        .inst   0xe7c953ee ; undefined
  400134:       d3437b0f        ubfx    x15, x24, #3, #28
  400138:       2edb19d4        .inst   0x2edb19d4 ; undefined
  40013c:       9350921e        sbfx    x30, x16, #16, #21
  400140:       ea5adf9d        ands    x29, x28, x26, lsr #55

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000042010018 <code>:
    42010018:   00020026        .word   0x00020026
    4201001c:   00000000        .word   0x00000000

0000000042010020 <status>:
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the details here, I will try it out on my system and revert back.

Comment: in the actual test you still have secure="on", doesn't that mean it is retrieving ICH_HCR_EL2 at EL3 and not EL2?

Comment: No, it does not - the program runs without causing an exception at both EL3 and EL3. I just fixed the copy/paste error you pointed out in the shell script above, thank you.